# What is a clean way to show an edit page on a windows phone app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a standard way to put up an entry form in WP7 silverlight?

I'm currently planning on using the NavigationService to navigate to another page, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the best way is to have a separate page. As keyboardP mentioned you can potentially have weird navigation issues IF on completion of the edit you navigate back to the screen you came from. This gives you a stack that looks like

```
List Page (then navigate to Edit Page)
List Page -> Edit Page (then hit Save)
List Page -> Edit Page -> List Page
```

This isn't good because the user hits back and they end up on the Edit Page. The better solution is rather than calling Navigate, you call "GoBack" to take you back to the ListPage, this gives you a stack like.

```
List Page (then navigate to Edit Page)
List Page -> Edit Page (then hit Save)
List Page
```

This also gives you advantage of being able to navigate to the edit page from anywhere in your app and it'll move straight back to where they came from.